# How to specify tmpfs size in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker-compose

How to specify a `tmpfs` volume size in a `docker-compose.yml` v2.x file?

Answer (score 0):

If the head of your yml file is:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  service_name_foobar:
    ...
    volumes:
      - foo:/tmp
```

you may specify the tmpfs options like this, for a 7 GB volume:

```
volumes:
  foo:
    driver_opts:
      type: tmpfs
      device: tmpfs
      o: "size=7g"
```